# Simple tar implementation?

Tags: c, tar

Hallo,

I'm looking for a really simple and easily hackable tar library for C or C++. Ideally it should have a permissive license (BSD/LGPL) and not have a ton of Unix/Windows OS dependencies, as I plan to use it from an embedded RTOS...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tar format is pretty simple.  Have you considered writing your own tar library?

Comment: It was very easy :)  Definitely less work than porting some library. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used it myself, but have you tried [libtar](http://www.feep.net/libtar/)? It is written in C and BSD licensed.

Comment: Of course it's pretty good, but the Unix dependencies are relatively heavy. So I would like something more lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the tar tool that comes on NetBSD.

It is actually a compound tool of pax, tar, and cpio, I believe you'll learn most from that.

http://people.freebsd.org/~kientzle/libarchive/